# Why do i keep having this error message : Warning, Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate

Tags: matlab, nls

I am trying to recreate the work in the paper : [Artificial-Neural-Network-Based Phase-Locking Scheme for Active Power Filters](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6616568) by [Mohammad M. K. Qasim](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohammad_Qasim14/info)
 & al.

In Section 2 : **FREQUENCY ESTIMATION USING NLS**, He state :

[image: Part1]
[image: Part2]

Then He say :

> since A is not invertible (i.e., A is not a square matrix) for the
>   overdetermined system of linear equations, it is not possible to solve
>   (6) directly. This problem can be easily solved by taking the
>   pseudoinverse of A

---

**Question :**

I want to calculate a Matrix U, where the variable is f0 (in A matrix)
 :[image: Equation]

Here is my code :

```
%% Creating a distored signal (VS)

fs = 20000; % sampling freq = 20KHz
st = 1/fs;
t = 0:st:((1/50)/2)-st; % half a cycle
f0 = 50; % fundamental freq
N = 5;

vfund = 220*sin(2*pi*f0.*t);

vc3 = 50*cos(2*pi*3*f0.*t); % Cos/k=3/amp=50
vc7 = 30*cos(2*pi*7*f0.*t); % Cos/k=7/amp=30

vs5 = 40*sin(2*pi*5*f0.*t); % Sin/k=5/amp=40
vs9 = 10*sin(2*pi*9*f0.*t); % Sin/k=2/amp=10

vTot = vfund + vc3 + vs5 + vc7 + vs9;

close all;
plot(t, vTot, t, vfund);

%% Trying to calculate U for f0 = 48.5
f0_es = 48.5; % example 

A = zeros(length(t), 5); % predeclaring A

% calculating A for the value of f0=48.5
for i=1:5
    A(:, 1) = sin(2*pi*f0_es.*t); %Fund
    A(:, 2) = cos(2*pi*f0_es*3.*t); %Cos3
    A(:, 3) = cos(2*pi*f0_es*7.*t); %Cos7
    A(:, 4) = sin(2*pi*f0_es*5.*t); %Sin4
    A(:, 5) = sin(2*pi*f0_es*9.*t); %Sin7
end

% Calculating U
At = pinv(A); % Step 1 : pseudo inverse of A
id = (A*At); % Step 2 : A*At
idminus = id^-1; % Step 3 : (A*At)^-1
p2 = At*idminus*A; % Step 4 : (A*(A*AT)^-1*A)
p1 = eye(5)-p2; % Step 5 : (I-(A*(A*AT)^-1*A))
```

1- Is my code right, am i calculating U correctly as in the equation Uf?

2- i keep receiving an error message : Warning, Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate

Comment: `At = A.'`, it is the transposed, not the inverse. `A*pinv(A)` is an identity matrix by definition.